# Can NASCAR SimRacing run on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backwards-compatibility, nascar-simracing

I'm trying to run this game on my Windows 7 Home Premium, but the game does nothing. So far I've tried native and Windows XP Compatibility Mode. The game is updated to Beta 1.0.29. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the publisher and Microsoft: Nope.](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Software&p=Nascar%20SimRacing&v=EA&uid=&pf=1&pi=3&c=PC%20Gaming&sc=Sports&os=32-bit)

However, it looks like if you own NASCAR Thunder (or install [the demo](http://download.cnet.com/NASCAR-Thunder-2004-demo/3000-7518_4-10239777.html)) you can steal one of its files, and the mutant game will work.  Paraphrased from [this forum post](http://www.poj-iyd.com/forum_topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=170&FORUM_ID=53&CAT_ID=6&Forum_Title=Nascar+simracing&Topic_Title=Nascar+Sim+Racing+will+work+on+Windows+7) and [another](http://www.poj-iyd.com/forum_topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=151&FORUM_ID=47&CAT_ID=6&Topic_Title=Nascar+Sim+Racing+will+work+on+Windows+7&Forum_Title=Nascar+simracing):

> Open the folder where you installed NASCAR Thunder, copy 3Dconfig.exe, paste it in the folder where you installed NASCAR Simracing, and rename it 3Dsetup.exe. Then run the 3Dsetup program. Make sure you've downloaded all the upgrades.

Comment: That's a crazy idea that just might work! So let me get the steps right:
1. Download and install NASCAR Thunder demo.
2. Install NASCAR SimRacing.
3. Copy 3Dconfig.exe from NASCAR Thunder to NASCAR SimRacing, and once there rename it 3Dsetup.exe and run it from the SimRacing folder.

I guess my only questions are: will this re-install NASCAR SimRacing? What upgrades should I have downloaded, for NASCAR Thunder or NASCAR SimRacing? Thanks!

Comment: @Rodrigo Yep, that's it. It shouldn't do any re-installation. I would make sure you've patched SimRacing first, sounds like you already have; I don't think anything else should be necessary.